# Slice/Split on the n'th occurence in JS

Tags: javascript

I have an array made up of strings separated by "|":

```
LOG: 380|2|choice|Question_8_13240_1351170102936|||incorrect|2012-10-25T15:01:13|1|<ln>380|2|choice|Question_10_13280_1351170102995|||incorrect|2012-10-25T15:01:17|1|
```

and need to get Question_8_13240_1351170102936 from each string so that i can see if there are any dupicate questions thus the string after the 3rd occurence of "|" and before the 4th

the code that build the array:

```
 AssessmentManager.prototype.submit = function () {
  assessData = "";
  assessmentItemsLength = this.assessmentItems.length;
  for (i = 0; i < this.assessmentItems.length; i++) {
    if (!this.assessmentItems[i].getSubmitted()) {
      assessmentFlatDataItem = this.assessmentItems[i].getFlatData();
      if (assessmentFlatDataItem.length > 0) {
        if (assessData.length > 0)
          assessData += "<ln>";
          assessData += assessmentFlatDataItem;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

then GetFlatdata:

```
  AssessmentItem.prototype.getFlatData = function () {
  result = _userScormModuleId + "|";

  if (this._interactionIdx)
    result += this._interactionIdx;
  result += "|";

  if (this._interactionType)
    result += this._interactionType
  result += "|";

  if (this._interactionId)
    result += this._interactionId
  result += "|";

  if (this._learnerResponse)
    result += this._learnerResponse
  result += "|";

  if (this._correctResponse)
    result += this._correctResponse
  result += "|";

  if (this._result)
    result += this._result
  result += "|";

  if (this._timeStamp)
   result += this._timeStamp
  result += "|";

 if (this._weighting)
   result += this._weighting
 result += "|";

 if (this._description)
  result += this._description

  return result;
}
```

how will i achieve this?
thanks

i have this now:

```
 learnerResponsesArray.push({ 
    key: j,
    value:  this.assessmentItems.split('<ln>')
  });
```

then loop through learnerResponsesArray?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to serialize your data with pipe delimiters, rather than trying something like JSON? It seems to me that your data could be set in the more descriptive language of JSON to make parsing easier.

Comment: There are many asses in the code. To the point: Split into lines as `data.split('<ln>')` and check each using `line.split('|')[3]`

Comment: i need to get all those strings between 3rd and 4th "|" please. maybe once i have all those i can put them in an array and check the array for dups? please help it is quite urgent :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var cells = mystring.split("|");
// nth item...
var myitem = cells[n];
```

but as @mori57 said, why use this format instead of JSON?

Comment: Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
str = "LOG: 380|2|choice|Question_8_13240_1351170102936|||incorrect|2012-10-25T15:01:13|1|<ln>380|2|choice|Question_10_13280_1351170102995|||incorrect|2012-10-25T15:01:17|1| "
console.log(str.split(":")[1].split("|")[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the value between the 3d and 4th `|`, you could use:

```
var fourthelement = [yourstring].split(/\|/,4).pop();
```